# Django-Grappeli: Maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-grappelli

I have installed Grappelli Cms of Django, as indicated [here](https://django-grappelli.readthedocs.org/en/2.4.5/quickstart.html#installation)

After that installation, when I call the admin page the error is:

```
RuntimeError:maximum recursion depth exceeded.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Regards

Alessandro

Comment: Please add your stacktrace

Comment: Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
Django Version:  1.5.1
Exception Type:  RuntimeError
Exception Value:  

maximum recursion depth exceeded

Exception Location:  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py in get_language, line 211
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:  2.7.3